# Unable to get the column keys from mysql into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a Xampp server running, I'm trying to fetch a table from mysql database in a pandas dataframe, Data is being fetched perfectly, however keys are not being set, help will be highly appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

my_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    username="",
    password="",
    database="test",
)
mycursor = my_db.cursor()

mycursor.execute('Select * from customers')
data = mycursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples. So, pandas has no way of knowing the column names.

You can use `mycursor.description` to find the column names and use that while creating the DataFrame

```
columns = [col[0] for col in mycursor.description]
data = mycursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```